Forcing Maven to lock versions to those in one repository
We're maintaining several programs, which communicate with a large vendor-provided application using the application's APIs. The application's code itself uses a number of 3rd-party JARs, which makes it necessary for our programs to use the same too.
Those JARs are provided by the vendor -- in the application-directory -- in the form very similar to a Maven-repository: the JARs are all under $VENDORTOP/repository/$package/$version/$package-$version.jar. There are neither .pom files, nor checksums there, but Maven still uses the repository described as:
<repository>
    <id>App</id>
    <name>Local App installation</name>
    <url>file://${VENDORTOP}/repository/</url>
</repository>

However, when the other repositories (such as "central") offer newer versions of the same JARs, Maven prefers those newer ones.
This behavior makes sense to me as a default, but is it possible to change it? Can I somehow tell Maven to stick to whatever is available in the given repository -- even if other repositories offer a newer version for the same artifact?
Yes, we could change the programs' pom.xml files to lock the versions of the dependencies to those bundled by the vendor (instead of version-ranges we're using now). But that'd be painful and tedious, because we have different versions of that application -- which bundle slightly different versions of the 3rd-party artifacts too.
Still, we'd like each program built to work with an application-instance to use exactly the JARs used by the instance itself. How would we do that?
(Using Maven-3.9.6 and Java-11 on RHEL-7.)

This does not answer my question, @khmarbaise...
